# how can I export table content to excel or csv

Tags: 6, importing-exporting

I am using drupal 6, I have created a table using

```
$tableHeader = array (     
  array('data' => 'Ebooks','field' => 'etitle'),
  array('data' => 'Volumes','field' => 'Volume' ),        
  array('data' => 'Chapter','field' => 'ctitle'),
  array('data' => 'Total Sale'),
);

$TableRows[] = array (
  l($row->etitle,$ebookinfo),
  $row->name,                              
  str_replace("&amp;", "&" ,$row->ctitle ),                             
  round($row->totalsale,2).' $',
); 

$output .= theme('table', $tableHeader, $TableRows);// get the pager
$output .= theme('pager', NULL, 5, 0);
```

How can I export it to MS Excel or CSV?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe the following code can help you.

```php
$filename= 'export.csv';
drupal_set_header('Content-Type: text/csv');
drupal_set_header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
```

You can add a function to send the row values, filename, and column title.

```php
function export_to_excel_page($row_array, $filename, $column_titles) {
  drupal_set_header('Content-Type: text/csv');
  drupal_set_header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
    
  foreach ($column_titles as $key => $value) {
    $keys[] = $value;           
  }
            
  if ($keys) {
    print implode(',', $keys) ."\r\n";
    unset($keys);
  }
    
  foreach ($row_array as $key => $value) {
    $values[] =$value; 
  }

  print implode(',', $values) ."\r\n";
  unset($values);

  drupal_exit();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's an updated function that should work for D7.

```
<?php
/**
 * Exports a CSV.
 *
 * @param array $variables
 *   An associative array of data containing "header" and "rows" keys.
 *   This is ready to be passed to theme_table(). See api.drupal.org/node/22950.
 *   Also contains the key "filename" specifying the filename.
 */
function _epc_standards_statistics_export_csv($variables) {
  drupal_add_http_header('Content-Type', 'text/csv; utf-8');
  drupal_add_http_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' . $variables['filename']);

  $output = '';
  $keys = array();
  foreach ($variables['header'] as $key => $value) {
    $keys[] = $value['data'];
  }
  if ($keys) {
    $output .= implode("\t", $keys) . "\n";
  }
  foreach ($variables['rows'] as $value) {
    $output .= implode("\t", $value) . "\n";
  }
  print $output;
  exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use drupal_exit() https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_exit/7 ?

Comment: Separating values with tabs would make it a TSV (Tab Separated Values) file instead of a CSV.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to export Nodes content, then you can able to use [views_data_export](http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module and export content using views !

> This module is designed to provide a way to export large amounts of
>   data from views. It provides a display plugin that can rendered
>   progressively in a batch. Style plugins are included that support
>   exporting in the following types:
>
> CSV, Microsoft XLS, Microsoft DOC, Basic, TXT, XML.

If you want to export database tables data then you can consider [data](http://drupal.org/project/data) module.

> Data module helps you model, manage and query related sets of tables.
>   It offers an administration interface and a low level API for
>   manipulating tables and accessing their contents. Data module provides
>   Views integration for displaying table data and Drupal search
>   integration for searching table content.

Comment: Dear Anil Sagar, thanks for suggestion, but i need to export data from custom tables. as i generated table from that data i want to export those tables, and i am not using views.

Comment: You can use phpmyadmin that works with mysql to export tables or query results to CSV format easily ! Try data module too as it tells it can export tables date to CSV!

Comment: I have to provide a UI to user that shows data and if they need then they can export data  in csv or excel. i have completed the UI but i have to give export functionality to users to export the table content.